# what is the use of AtomicInteger inside lock

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java-8, atomic

In this section from java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.put() method, I think there is no need of AtomicInteger. Considering there is only one thread inside lock(). Am I correct?

```
putLock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count.get() == capacity) {
            notFull.await();
        }
        enqueue(node);
        c = count.getAndIncrement();
        if (c + 1 < capacity)
            notFull.signal();
    } finally {
        putLock.unlock();
    }
```

I checked many questions, but can not find answer. My question: there is only one thread inside lock, so why to use AtomicInteger here

Comment: for the producer/consumer queue it is needed. since they are in different threads. `put` is the producer endpoint, and `take` is the consumer endpoint.

Comment: oh yes, I completely missed that point. Agree with you. Thanks

Comment: Besides the fact that `put` and `take` use different locks, there is also access without holding a lock at all, e.g. in `size()` or `remainingCapacity()`. Also `peek()` and `poll()` (without timeout) take shortcuts without locking when `count` is zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `LinkedBlockingQueue` uses two different locks, `putLock` and `takeLock` to allow concurrent `put` and `take` operation to proceed without blocking each other, assuming that there are already nodes in the queue but the capacity has not exhausted (or not limited at all).

So it this case, `count` may be accessed by two threads concurrently. Since the consumer and producer threads use different locks, the locks themselves do not establish the necessary memory visibility guarantees between the producer and consumer, it is in fact the atomic update of the `count` which does.

Besides that, there are also non-blocking operations, like `size()` or `remainingCapacity()` which access `count` without holding a lock. Also, some operations, like `peek()` and `poll()` (without timeout) have a short-cut, testing `count` for zero before acquiring the lock, to return `null` immediately without locking when the count is zero.

Comment: `use different locks, the locks themselves do not establish the necessary memory visibility guarantees` - excellent! generally locks do establish memory visibility, but they have to be the *same* locks used by all threads

Answer (score 5):

There are two locks there:

```
private final ReentrantLock putLock = new ReentrantLock();

private final ReentrantLock takeLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

The `put` method is indeed protected by the `putLock`, but any other thread accessing `count` can still update it (unless it's another `put`). To make sure it is correctly updated it has to be `Atomic`.